# Redirect Error: No such label 'stdexten' in extension

Tags: asterisk

i have install asterisk 11 on my server but when i want to redirect to extensions, i catch this error:

NOTICE[12657][C-00000043]: pbx.c:4475 pbx_extension_helper: No such label 'stdexten' in extension '305' in context 'DLPN_DialPlan'

WARNING[12657][C-00000043]: pbx.c:11825 pbx_parseable_goto: Priority 'stdexten' must be a number > 0, or valid label

ERROR[12657][C-00000043]: app_stack.c:547 gosub_exec: Gosub address is invalid: '305,stdexten(SIP/305)'

i think that this must be a bug in asterisk. anybody know about this???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Goto([[context|]extension|]priority)

Set the priority to the specified value, optionally setting the extension and optionally the context as well. The extension BYEXTENSION is special in that it uses the current extension, thus permitting you to go to a different context, without specifying a specific extension. Please note that the LEADING arguments to Goto() are optional, not the trailing arguments.

Answer (score 1):

I think that you are probably using a Goto with just an extension. This won't work - When using Goto, if you wish to go to a different exntension, then you must also specify the label or line number you want to go to.

[Here's a useful reference on Goto in Asterisk](http://www.voip-info.org/wiki/view/Asterisk+cmd+Goto)

Here are the various combinations of parameters that work:

- Goto(context,extension,priority)
- Goto(extension,priority)
- Goto(priority)
- Goto(context,extension,label)
- Goto(extension,label)
- Goto(label)

Contexts are groups of extensions in extensions.conf. The start of a context looks like this: `[Hello_World_Context]`

Extensions are groups of commands that get executed if the call matches the number pattern. They're usually a bunch of commands which start with `exten =>`, such as: `exten => 100,1,Answer`

A priority is basically a line number. An example: `exten => 100,1,Answer` has a priority of 1.

A label can be used instead of a priority/line number. Example: `exten => 100,n(extension_name),Answer` - This has a label of `exension_name`